# storing variables in webserver with nodejs and express

Tags: node.js, json, express, npm

i'm trying to create a web server that saves variables to a webserver on each situation, due to caching is it possible?,
like res.send(data)
i'm trying to make something like webdb(not sure if works)

> This Webserver Uses Express
> edit:
> SOLVED
> **_**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have two main options in order to save your data values on the server-side:

1> save on the memory of your server using "Redis" data store.
[Beginner’s Guide to Redis and Caching with NodeJS](https://livecodestream.dev/post/beginners-guide-to-redis-and-caching-with-nodejs/)

2> save on the hard disk databases like using (MySQL db or mango db etc).

if your Json variable size is about small and it needs frequently used with your code the Redis memory store is a good option. (for session use also). if you rarely need to access the data or the size is high or another reason, mango db/MySQL db will be used.

(for caching purpose option 1 is better)